# How can I get hold of all the arguments passed to a method with MooseX::Method::Signatures?

Tags: perl, oop, moose

If I use [`MooseX::Method::Signatures`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Method::Signatures), and I want to pass all the arguments onto a  second method, I have to explicitly list them again:

```
method foo (Str :$bar!, Int: :$baz!) {
    ...
    return $self->_foo2(bar => $bar, baz => $baz);
}
```

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
method foo (Str :$bar!, Int: :$baz!) {
    ...
    return $self->_foo2(%args);
}
```

This documentation for [`Method::Signatures`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures#pod-_) suggests I can use `@_` but that drops the named parameter keys.

Comment: Are you using Method::Signatures, or MooseX::Method::Signatures? They're significantly different modules!

Comment: Yes sorry, a bit confusing there. I am using MooseX::Method::Signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done a little testing, it seems like MooseX::Method::Signatures is the "odd one out" of the major implementations of method signatures. All the others allow you to use `@_` as expected; MXMS does not.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More 0.96;

{
  package MyBase;
  sub new { bless {}, shift }
  sub _foo { \@_ }
}

{
  package UseKavorka;
  use Kavorka;
  use parent -norequire => qw(MyBase);

  method foo (Str :$bar!, Int :$baz!) {
    $self->_foo(@_);
  }
}

{
  package UseMS;
  use Method::Signatures;
  use parent -norequire => qw(MyBase);

  method foo (Str :$bar!, Int :$baz!) {
    $self->_foo(@_);
  }
}

{
  package UseMXMS;
  use Moose;
  use MooseX::Method::Signatures;
  extends qw(MyBase);

  method foo (Str :$bar!, Int :$baz!) {
    $self->_foo(@_);
  }
}

{
  package UseFP;
  use Function::Parameters;
  use parent -norequire => qw(MyBase);

  method foo (Str :$bar, Int :$baz) {
    $self->_foo(@_);
  }
}

for my $class (qw/ UseKavorka UseMS UseMXMS UseFP /)
{
  my $obj = $class->new;
  is_deeply(
    $obj->foo(bar => "Hello world", baz => 42),
    [ $obj, bar => "Hello world", baz => 42 ],
    "\@_ worked fine in $class",
  );
}

done_testing;

__END__
ok 1 - @_ worked fine in UseKavorka
ok 2 - @_ worked fine in UseMS
not ok 3 - @_ worked fine in UseMXMS
#   Failed test '@_ worked fine in UseMXMS'
#   at foo.pl line 55.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[1] = UseMXMS=HASH(0x92c0cc8)
#     $expected->[1] = 'bar'
ok 4 - @_ worked fine in UseFP
1..4
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
```

I'm biased because I wrote it, but my advice is to switch to [Kavoka](https://metacpan.org/release/Kavorka) which gives you pretty much all the features of MooseX::Method::Signatures, but without the massive slow down.